# Show that $\mathfrak{F}_A$ is a filter on $X$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Let $A\subseteq X$ be fixed non-empty subset of $X$. Show that the set of subsets of $X$ that contains $A$ is a filter on $X$.

My proof-trying.

Let $\mathfrak{F}_A:=${$B\subseteq X:$ $A\subseteq B$}.

Initially, assume $A\in\mathfrak{F}_A$ and $A\subseteq B\subseteq X$. We need to show that $B\in\mathfrak{F}_A$. Since $A\subseteq X$, $A\subseteq A$ and $ B\subseteq X$,  $B\subseteq B$ then $B\in\mathfrak{F}_A$. **Can you check my proof-trying**?

Secondly, assume $A,B\in\mathfrak{F}_A$, we need to show that $A\cap B\in\mathfrak{F}_A$. **So, what should I do?**

Finally, we need to show that $\emptyset$ is not in $\mathfrak{F}_A$ and $X\in\mathfrak{F}_A$. **Can you help?**

Comment: definition of filter is in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Filter.html

Comment: You're reusing the letter $A$, with different meanings. Firstly, $A$ is used in the definition of $\mathfrak F_A$. Secondly, $A$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathfrak F_A$ in the course of your proof. Perhaps go with a different letter in your proof.

Comment: part of your confusion comes from the fact, that you use $A$ for a fixed set, and later for an arbitrary element of the filter

Comment: Assume $A'\in\mathfrak{F}_A $ and $A'\subseteq B'\subseteq X$. We need to show that $B'\in\mathfrak{F}_A$. Since $A'\in\mathfrak{F}_A$ then $A'\subseteq, A\subseteq A'$ and since $A'\subseteq B'\subseteq X$, then $B'\subseteq X$,  $A\subseteq B'$. Therefore, $B'\in\mathfrak{F}_A$, right?

Comment: @FreeChoice can you check my last comment?

Comment: @martin.koeberl can you check my last comment?

Comment: That proof in your comment is good.

Answer (score 3):

(1) Let $C \in \mathfrak{F}_A$. Assume that $D \supset C$. Then $D\supset C \supset A \implies D \supset A \implies D \in \mathfrak{F}_A$.

(2) Let $C,D \in \mathfrak{F}_A$. Then $A \subset C$ and $A \subset D$. Then it is clear that $A \subset C \cap D$.

(3) Assume that $\emptyset \in \mathfrak{F}_A$. Then $A \subset \emptyset$. Then $A =\emptyset$. But by assumption, $A \neq \emptyset$. Therefore, $\emptyset \not \in \mathfrak{F}_A$.